# Run java jar file with external liblaries problem

Tags: opencv, intellij-idea, javafx, jar, java-11

I'm having trouble running my old javafx application. The application requires two external libraries: openCV and javafx to run, so I try to run it with the command:

*`C:/Users/user/.jdks/corretto-11.0.9.1/bin/java.exe --module-path C:\Users\user\Desktop\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib;C:\opencv\build\java --add-modules javafx.controls,opencv-342 -jar myapp.jar`*

But i have error:
**Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module opencv-342 not found**

I checked several times if the opencv paths were correct.
Any ideas?

Comment: what files *are* in `C:\opencv\build\java`?